# determining how a simplemodal window was closed via an iframe or closeHTML, escClose or overlayClose

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal to display a form via an iframe. the form can close the modal and the onClose callback can refresh the main screen, updating information on the screen. but I would like to not have the main screen refresh if the iframe form doesn't close the modal. In other words, I would like to not refresh the screen on a simple close from closeHTML, escClose or overlayClose.

Is there a way in the onClose call back to determine what is closing the modal, if the close was called by way of closeHTML, escClose or overlayClose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this may get you on the right track.

- Edit the plugin to set a data attribute value for each type of closing
- Get the data attribute using the onClose callback

**Plugin code**

```
    // bind the close event to any element with the closeClass class
    $('.' + s.o.closeClass).bind('click.simplemodal', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // set 'closeType' data attr
        $('body').data('closetype', 'closeClass');
        s.close();

    });

    // bind the overlay click to the close function, if enabled
    if (s.o.modal && s.o.close && s.o.overlayClose) {
        s.d.overlay.bind('click.simplemodal', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // set 'closeType' data attr
            $('body').data('closetype', 'overlayClose');
            s.close();
        });
    }

    // bind keydown events
    doc.bind('keydown.simplemodal', function (e) {
        if (s.o.modal && e.keyCode === 9) { // TAB
            s.watchTab(e);
        }
        else if ((s.o.close && s.o.escClose) && e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
            e.preventDefault();
            // set 'closeType' data attr
            $('body').data('closetype', 'escClose');
            s.close();
        }
    });
```

**Plugin Initialization**

```
    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            overlayClose: true,
            onClose: function() {
                console.log($('body').data('closetype'));
                $.modal.close();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```